# Make "data" transient or serializable SonarQube Error

Tags: java, sonarqube, lombok

I have created this class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class Hostel<T> implements Serializable {

    @Field
    private Long version;   
    @JsonProperty("_data")
    private @NotNull T data;

}
```

But I have this SonarQube error:

```
Make "data" transient or serializable SonarQube Error
```

but data is a Generic type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it `transient`, or just bound `T` with `<T extends Serializable>`.

Answer (score 2):

`T` is unknown type here. So, it's unpredictable whether `T` is serializable or not. most of the inbuilt classes of java are serializable e.g. String, Map, List etc but when you use generic types it's unpredictable and hence bound it to be `Serializable` Or if you don't want it to be serialized then mark it `transient`.

Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) for more on bounded types